# layout XML doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

i don't know why but i have two content_main:content_main and content_main2 and in both content_main i have button; i want only one button.

I hope that you can help me!!!!!!!!

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!

this is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<!--<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">-->
   <!-- <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:capitalize="characters"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textSize="30dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantità2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>-->




       <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">

         <!--   <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/resultpizze"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:textSize="30sp"/>-->

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/result2"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:textSize="30sp"
               android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/resultbirre"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <!--   <TextView
               android:id="@+id/result"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:textSize="30sp"
               android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/resultpizze"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:textSize="30sp"/>-->

       </LinearLayout>
       <!-- <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_main3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resultpizze"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_main2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultpizze"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

       </LinearLayout>


<!--</ScrollView>-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="sendemail"
            android:text="Manda Email">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

MY LIST FRAGMENT:

```
 public class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    static PlanetAdapter plAdapter;

    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;
    private static Context context = null;
    private static FragmentActivity mInstance;





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //super.onDestroy();
        SharedPreferences settings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        context = getActivity();
        mInstance= getActivity();
        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showResult(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }




    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();


    }


    private void displayPlanetList() {

        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add(new Planet("Margherita", 6, "€",1));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", 7,"€",2));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", 5,"€",3));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", 5, "€",4));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", 4, "€", 5));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
                    p.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }
        };

        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
    }



    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//*
        }*/

    }


/*
    public static void showResult(View v) {
        String  result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount=0;
        String  result2 = "";
        int totalAmount2=0;

        String a="";
        String z="";



        for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.isSelected()){


                result2 += "\n" + p.getName()+" "+p.getDistance()+"€"+"q.tà :"+p.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità() );
                totalAmount2+=p.getDistance() * quantitaInt;
                //z=String.valueOf(totalAmount2);


            }
            int totale=totalAmount+totalAmount2;
            z=String.valueOf(totale);

        }

        Toast.makeText(context, result2 + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount2 + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result2 + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount2 + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        Bundle bun2 = new Bundle();
        bun2.putString("scelta", result2);
        ThreeFragment fgsearch2 = new ThreeFragment();
        fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = mInstance.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
        transaction2.commit();






*/
/*










    }


*/
public static  void showResult(View v) {
    String  result = "Selected Product are :";
    int totalAmount=0;
    String  result2 = "";
    int totalAmount2=0;

    String a="";
    String z="";

    for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
        if (p.isSelected()){


            result += "\n" + p.getName()+" "+p.getDistance()+"€"+"q.tà :"+p.getQuantità();
            int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità() );
            totalAmount2+=p.getDistance() * quantitaInt;
            z=String.valueOf(totalAmount2);



        }


    }

    Toast.makeText(context, result + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount2 + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result2 + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount2 + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    Bundle bun = new Bundle();
    bun.putString("scelta4", result);
    bun.putString("scelta5", z);

    TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
    fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = mInstance.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch);
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch);

    transaction.commit();





/*Bundle bun = new Bundle();
    //  bun.putString("totalepizze",z);
    bun.putInt("totalepizze",totalAmount2);
        TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
        fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = mInstance.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch);
        transaction.commit();*/

/*



        Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putString("scelta", result2);
        TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
        fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch);
        transaction.commit();

*/









}



}
```

THREE FRAGMENT:

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv2;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    ListView lv;

    ArrayList<Birra> birraList;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    Planet p;
    String myInt="";



    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;


    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyListFragment mlf=new MyListFragment();

                mlf.showResult(v);
              // MyListFragment.showResult(v);
                showResult2(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lv2 = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        displayBirraList();
    }


    private void displayBirraList() {

        birraList = new ArrayList<Birra>();
        birraList.add(new Birra("Paulaner", 6, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Forst", 7, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Peroni", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Corona", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Nastro Azzurro", 4, "€"));
        biAdapter = new BirraAdapter(birraList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int pos = lv2.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Birra b = birraList.get(pos);
                    b.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }


        };


        lv2.setAdapter(biAdapter);
    }


    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//**//**//**//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//**//**//**//*
        }
*/
    }


    public void showResult2(View v) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        String a="";
        int totalAmount = 0;
       // String a = "";


        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()) {

            if (b.selected) {

                result += "\n" + b.name + " " + b.distance + "€" + "q.tà :" + b.getQuantità();
                try {
                    int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                    totalAmount += b.distance * quantitaInt;
                      a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);
                    Bundle bun2 = new Bundle();
                    bun2.putString("scelta2", result);
                    bun2.putString("scelta3", a);
                    TwoFragment fgsearch2 = new TwoFragment();
                    fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                   transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch2);
                    transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch2);

                    transaction2.commit();
                    //android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction3 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                   // transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch2);
                   // transaction2.commit();

                  /*  Bundle bun3 = new Bundle();
                    bun3.putString("scelta3", a);
                    TwoFragment fgsearch3 = new TwoFragment();
                    fgsearch3.setArguments(bun3);
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction3 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction3.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch3);
                    transaction3.commit();*/
                }catch(NumberFormatException exc){
                    System.out.println(exc);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "inserisci una quantita' a \""+b.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //System.out.println("inserisci una quantita' a %s"+b.name);
                }

            }
        }
      /*  for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.isSelected()) {


                result += "\n" + p.getName() + " " + p.getDistance() + "€" + "q.tà :" + p.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità());
                //totalAmount2+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                //z=String.valueOf(totalAmount2);


            }
        }*/



        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" +myInt + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           //Bundle bun2 = new Bundle();
          // bun2.putString("scelta2", result);

     /*   TwoFragment fgsearch2 = new TwoFragment();
            fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
           android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
            transaction2.commit();*/

   /*     TwoFragment fgsearch2=TwoFragment.getInstance(result);
        fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
        transaction2.commit();
*/




      /*  Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putInt("totalebirre", totalAmount);
            TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
            fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch);
            transaction.commit();
*/



    }
}
```

TWO FRAGMENT:

```
public class TwoFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private View v;
    Intent chooser = null;
    String myInt = "";
    String ciao = "";
    private String string = "";
    private String string3 = "";
    private String string4 = "";
    private String string5 = "";

    int stringbirre=0;
    int stringpizze=0;
    int tot=0;
    private ProgressDialog processingDialog;
    private MakePDF mProgressbarAsync;
    private ProgressBar pdfProgress;
    private int mProgressStatus = 0;

    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        processingDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        processingDialog.setCancelable(true);
        processingDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        processingDialog.setMessage("Work in Progress ...");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);


        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newbutton);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //sendemail();
                // pdfProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                processingDialog.show();
                mProgressbarAsync=new MakePDF();
                mProgressbarAsync.execute();


            }
        });
        TextView titolo3 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.result);
        //TextView titolo2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.result2);
        TextView titolo4 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.resultpizze);
        TextView titolo5 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.result2);
        TextView titolo6 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.resultbirre);


        pdfProgress = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        pdfProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            string = bundle.getString("scelta4");
            titolo3.setText(string);
            string3 = bundle.getString("scelta5");
            titolo4.setText(string3);

        }

        Bundle bundle2 = getArguments();
        if (bundle2 != null) {


            string4 = bundle2.getString("scelta2");
            titolo5.setText(string4);
            string5 = bundle2.getString("scelta3");
            titolo6.setText(string5);

        }


        return rootView;
    }




    public void createPDF() {

        Document doc = new Document();

        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText";

            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

            File file = new File(dir, "salve.pdf");

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

            doc.open();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                    .getResources(), R.drawable.androtuto);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

            doc.add(myImg);
            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(string+string3);
            Font paraFont = new Font(Font.COURIER);
            p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p1.setFont(paraFont);


            doc.add(p1);

            Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(string4+string5);

            Font paraFont2 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
            p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p2.setFont(paraFont2);

            doc.add(p2);



            stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                    .getResources(), R.drawable.android);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

            doc.add(myImg);

            Phrase footerText = new Phrase("Pied de page ");
            HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
            doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);

        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + e.getMessage());


        } finally {
            doc.close();
        }

    }

    public void viewPDF() {
        String path = "/sdcard/droidText/salve.pdf";

        File targetFile = new File(path);
        Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);

        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }


private class MakePDF extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          mProgressStatus = 0;
      }


      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
          while(mProgressStatus<100){
              try{

                  mProgressStatus++;

                  publishProgress(mProgressStatus);

                  Thread.sleep(100);

              }catch(Exception e){
                  Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
              }
          }
          createPDF();
          return null;
      }


      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
          super.onProgressUpdate(values);
          processingDialog.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
      }


      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          processingDialog.dismiss();
          viewPDF();
      }
  }


}
```

titolo3 and titolo4 are null if i put theese two variables into a content_main(where there are also titolo5 and titolo6)...i don't know why....

Comment: Do you really require two content_main.xml?

Comment: if i use only one content_main i see result of only two variables no four...

Comment: where is your content_main2?

Comment: content_main2 contein result and resultpizze...you can see in my code

Comment: Check my answer, just copy paste the code. Hope it will help :)

Comment: Looking at your xml layout, it should display single button on the screen with 4 textViews on top. Are you trying to have one button on each content_main?

Comment: i want only one button for both content_main

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


       <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/result2"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textSize="30sp"
               android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/resultbirre"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textSize="30sp"/>

       </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_main2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultpizze"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

       </LinearLayout>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="sendemail"
            android:text="Manda Email"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Two buttons?? not possible.. Are you adding this layout to any other layout??

Comment: in "design" there is only one button...but when i click button to get answer about checkbox checked i go on twoFragment and i see two buttons

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this limited code snippet. Just try to debug the code.